# Unclosed element error in Ember template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Unclosed element `container.style.display` (on line 25).
```

Line 25 of my program is:

```
if ((container.style.opacity -= .01) <= 0)
```

But I think it's referring to the line below:

```
container.style.display = "none";
```

Why am I getting this error?

The context:

```
<script>
var container = document.getElementById('popUpContainer');

function popUpFadeOut() {
    if (container.style.opacity == 0) {
        container.style.opacity = 1;
        container.style.display = "block";

        var fading = function fade() {

            if ((container.style.opacity -= .01) <= 0) {
                container.style.display = "none";
                container.style.opacity = 0;
            } else {
                requestAnimationFrame(fade);
            }
        };

        setTimeout(fading, 1000); //popup box fades away after 1 seconds
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The current block of code is ok. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: `Unclosed element` - sounds like a problem with HTML, not javascript

Comment: It is telling me that the problem is in this file. Also, if I remove the fade() function and its content, there are no longer any errors.

Comment: Could you wrap your code into `<![CDATA[... code ... ]]>` ?

Comment: Where you have written this code ? i mean which js file ?

Comment: Well it would be well better to use `<script src="..."></script>` than inline code.

Comment: @kumkanillam It is written in my index.hbs file. Am I not allowed to write javascript in there?

Comment: Also doing a `-=` inside the if is bad practice. Hard to read and could lead to more errors. Move that part before the if.

Comment: write it in index.js route or create component and write it in .js file

Comment: @kumkanillam So I put the entire script inside export default Ember.Route.extend({
}); in index.js?

Comment: @torazaburo I'm using Chrome and I did not declare a doctype anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you mention comes in an HTML parsing context, most likely HTMLBars, meaning you are including a script in a template, which you shouldn't be doing in the first place.

The quick fix is to replace `<` with `&lt;`. The correct solution is to move the script from the template into a JS file where it belongs.

Note that this would not be a problem in an HTML file, because script tags (today) are "protected", and the only HTML inside of that that could cause a problem is something like `const foo = "</script>";`. It appears that the HTML parsing login in HTMLBars does not implement this "protection" mechanism. In theory this could be considered a bug, but no-one has ever worried about it, and no-one will ever fix it, because you shouldn't put script tags in templates anyway.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Do i create a folder called 'scripts' and put my scripts in there, or what is the best way to do this?

Comment: @Jesper Beyond the scope of a comment, but it seems like your code is trying to be a component, so you could implement it as an Ember component.

Comment: Script tags are not supported by design.